# XCode Clang Error involving output files (-o) while attempting to include header files

Tags: xcode

What does this error mean, and any ideas on how to fix it? The error message is:

"cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files"

I was trying to include the location of a downloaded folder in the Build Settings of my XCode project, in order to include a header in a .cpp file, and when I do this and the program sees the location of the header file (which is good), but I get the above error (which is the problem).

Comment: Solution: I just ran the program with the terminal via: clang++ main.cpp -o main, then, ./main

Comment: The XCode interface was causing problems...